# Rolling window in R

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I have part of this code which is the initial step of a rolling iteration

```
for (u in 1:5605){
  for (j in 1:498){
    work.on.col = j
    work.dt = data[u:(u+365),work.on.col] # u:(u+365-1)  considers the rolling window
  }
}
```

So basically, this makes a rolling window from `u == 1` to `u == 5605` for each `j`. However, this is a step by step (or in this case: a day by day) rolling algorithm. What I want to change it to, is to do so

1. By 30 days: instead or rolling day by day, it should roll every 30 days (by this I meant here that the rolling window will REMOVE 30 days, then add 30 days to the window, thus rolling the 365 day-long window). OR
2. By identifying the month. For example, first iteration will start with daily data from January 2000 to January 2001. And the next iteration will start with February 2000 to February 2001, and so on (this approach is more preferable).

#### Data

```
> dput(data)  
structure(list(Dates = structure(c(820454400, 820540800, 820627200, 
820713600, 820800000, 821059200, 821145600, 821232000, 821318400, 
821404800, 821664000, 821750400, 821836800, 821923200, 822009600, 
822268800, 822355200, 822441600, 822528000, 822614400, 822873600, 
822960000, 823046400, 823132800, 823219200, 823478400, 823564800, 
823651200, 823737600, 823824000, 824083200, 824169600, 824256000, 
824342400, 824428800, 824688000, 824774400, 824860800, 824947200, 
825033600, 825292800, 825379200, 825465600, 825552000, 825638400, 
825897600, 825984000, 826070400, 826156800, 826243200, 826502400, 
826588800, 826675200, 826761600, 826848000, 827107200, 827193600, 
827280000, 827366400, 827452800, 827712000, 827798400, 827884800, 
827971200, 828057600, 828316800, 828403200, 828489600, 828576000, 
828662400, 828921600, 829008000, 829094400, 829180800, 829267200, 
829526400, 829612800, 829699200, 829785600, 829872000, 830131200, 
830217600, 830304000, 830390400, 830476800, 830736000, 830822400, 
830908800, 830995200, 831081600, 831340800, 831427200, 831513600, 
831600000, 831686400, 831945600, 832032000, 832118400, 832204800, 
832291200, 832550400, 832636800, 832723200, 832809600, 832896000, 
833155200, 833241600, 833328000, 833414400, 833500800, 833760000, 
833846400, 833932800, 834019200, 834105600, 834364800, 834451200, 
834537600, 834624000, 834710400, 834969600, 835056000, 835142400, 
835228800, 835315200, 835574400, 835660800, 835747200, 835833600, 
835920000, 836179200, 836265600, 836352000, 836438400, 836524800, 
836784000, 836870400, 836956800, 837043200, 837129600, 837388800, 
837475200, 837561600, 837648000, 837734400, 837993600, 838080000, 
838166400, 838252800, 838339200, 838598400, 838684800, 838771200, 
838857600, 838944000, 839203200, 839289600, 839376000, 839462400, 
839548800, 839808000, 839894400, 839980800, 840067200, 840153600, 
840412800, 840499200, 840585600, 840672000, 840758400, 841017600, 
841104000, 841190400, 841276800, 841363200, 841622400, 841708800, 
841795200, 841881600, 841968000, 842227200, 842313600, 842400000, 
842486400, 842572800, 842832000, 842918400, 843004800, 843091200, 
843177600, 843436800, 843523200, 843609600, 843696000, 843782400, 
844041600, 844128000, 844214400, 844300800, 844387200, 844646400, 
844732800, 844819200, 844905600, 844992000, 845251200, 845337600, 
845424000, 845510400, 845596800, 845856000, 845942400, 846028800, 
846115200, 846201600, 846460800, 846547200, 846633600, 846720000, 
846806400, 847065600, 847152000, 847238400, 847324800, 847411200, 
847670400, 847756800, 847843200, 847929600, 848016000, 848275200, 
848361600, 848448000, 848534400, 848620800, 848880000, 848966400, 
849052800, 849139200, 849225600, 849484800, 849571200, 849657600, 
849744000, 849830400, 850089600, 850176000, 850262400, 850348800, 
850435200, 850694400, 850780800, 850867200, 850953600, 851040000, 
851299200, 851385600, 851472000, 851558400, 851644800, 851904000, 
851990400, 852076800, 852163200, 852249600, 852508800, 852595200, 
852681600, 852768000, 852854400, 853113600, 853200000, 853286400, 
853372800, 853459200, 853718400, 853804800, 853891200, 853977600, 
854064000, 854323200, 854409600, 854496000, 854582400, 854668800, 
854928000, 855014400, 855100800, 855187200, 855273600, 855532800, 
855619200, 855705600, 855792000, 855878400, 856137600, 856224000, 
856310400, 856396800, 856483200, 856742400, 856828800, 856915200, 
857001600, 857088000, 857347200, 857433600, 857520000, 857606400, 
857692800, 857952000, 858038400, 858124800, 858211200, 858297600, 
858556800, 858643200, 858729600, 858816000, 858902400, 859161600, 
859248000, 859334400, 859420800, 859507200, 859766400, 859852800, 
859939200, 860025600, 860112000, 860371200, 860457600, 860544000, 
860630400, 860716800, 860976000, 861062400, 861148800, 861235200, 
861321600, 861580800, 861667200, 861753600, 861840000, 861926400, 
862185600, 862272000, 862358400, 862444800, 862531200, 862790400, 
862876800, 862963200, 863049600, 863136000, 863395200, 863481600, 
863568000, 863654400, 863740800, 8.64e+08, 864086400, 864172800, 
864259200, 864345600, 864604800, 864691200, 864777600, 864864000, 
864950400, 865209600, 865296000, 865382400, 865468800, 865555200, 
865814400, 865900800, 865987200, 866073600, 866160000, 866419200, 
866505600, 866592000, 866678400, 866764800, 867024000, 867110400, 
867196800, 867283200, 867369600, 867628800, 867715200, 867801600, 
867888000, 867974400, 868233600, 868320000, 868406400, 868492800, 
868579200, 868838400, 868924800, 869011200, 869097600, 869184000, 
869443200, 869529600, 869616000, 869702400, 869788800, 870048000, 
870134400, 870220800, 870307200, 870393600, 870652800, 870739200, 
870825600, 870912000, 870998400, 871257600, 871344000, 871430400, 
871516800, 871603200, 871862400, 871948800, 872035200, 872121600, 
872208000, 872467200, 872553600, 872640000, 872726400, 872812800, 
873072000, 873158400, 873244800, 873331200, 873417600, 873676800, 
873763200, 873849600, 873936000, 874022400, 874281600, 874368000, 
874454400, 874540800, 874627200, 874886400, 874972800, 875059200, 
875145600, 875232000, 875491200, 875577600, 875664000, 875750400, 
875836800, 876096000, 876182400, 876268800, 876355200, 876441600, 
876700800, 876787200, 876873600, 876960000, 877046400, 877305600, 
877392000, 877478400, 877564800, 877651200, 877910400, 877996800, 
878083200, 878169600, 878256000, 878515200, 878601600, 878688000, 
878774400, 878860800, 879120000, 879206400, 879292800, 879379200, 
879465600, 879724800, 879811200, 879897600, 879984000, 880070400, 
880329600, 880416000, 880502400, 880588800, 880675200, 880934400, 
881020800, 881107200, 881193600, 881280000, 881539200, 881625600, 
881712000, 881798400, 881884800, 882144000, 882230400, 882316800, 
882403200, 882489600, 882748800, 882835200, 882921600, 883008000, 
883094400, 883353600, 883440000, 883526400, 883612800, 883699200, 
883958400, 884044800, 884131200, 884217600, 884304000, 884563200, 
884649600, 884736000, 884822400, 884908800, 885168000, 885254400, 
885340800, 885427200, 885513600, 885772800, 885859200, 885945600, 
886032000, 886118400, 886377600, 886464000, 886550400, 886636800, 
886723200, 886982400, 887068800, 887155200, 887241600, 887328000, 
887587200, 887673600, 887760000, 887846400, 887932800, 888192000, 
888278400, 888364800, 888451200, 888537600, 888796800, 888883200, 
888969600, 889056000, 889142400, 889401600, 889488000, 889574400, 
889660800, 889747200, 890006400, 890092800, 890179200, 890265600, 
890352000, 890611200, 890697600, 890784000, 890870400, 890956800, 
891216000, 891302400, 891388800, 891475200, 891561600, 891820800, 
891907200, 891993600, 892080000, 892166400, 892425600, 892512000, 
892598400, 892684800, 892771200, 893030400, 893116800, 893203200, 
893289600, 893376000, 893635200, 893721600, 893808000, 893894400, 
893980800, 894240000, 894326400, 894412800, 894499200, 894585600, 
894844800, 894931200, 895017600, 895104000, 895190400, 895449600, 
895536000, 895622400, 895708800, 895795200, 896054400, 896140800, 
896227200, 896313600, 896400000, 896659200, 896745600, 896832000, 
896918400, 897004800, 897264000, 897350400, 897436800, 897523200, 
897609600, 897868800, 897955200, 898041600, 898128000, 898214400, 
898473600, 898560000, 898646400, 898732800, 898819200, 899078400, 
899164800, 899251200, 899337600, 899424000, 899683200, 899769600, 
899856000, 899942400, 900028800, 900288000, 900374400, 900460800, 
900547200, 900633600, 900892800, 900979200, 901065600, 901152000, 
901238400, 901497600, 901584000, 901670400, 901756800, 901843200, 
902102400, 902188800, 902275200, 902361600, 902448000, 902707200, 
902793600, 902880000, 902966400, 903052800, 903312000, 903398400, 
903484800, 903571200, 903657600, 903916800, 904003200, 904089600, 
904176000, 904262400, 904521600, 904608000, 904694400, 904780800, 
904867200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `1` = c(9.3424, 
9.3424, 9.3983, 9.5102, 9.3144, 9.4822, 9.3983, 9.0537, 9.1381, 
9.1099, 9.0537, 8.9975, 8.7444, 8.8007, 8.8007, 8.7163, 8.8569, 
8.9412, 8.9131, 9.0537, 9.0537, 9.4474, 9.5036, 9.6723, 9.6723, 
9.7566, 9.5879, 9.7566, 9.841, 9.8129, 9.9535, 9.841, 9.6442, 
9.8972, 9.7285, 9.7285, 9.6161, 9.2787, 9.3911, 9.363, 9.2224, 
9.1099, 9.2787, 9.3911, 9.4474, 9.841, 9.7285, 9.7004, 9.8691, 
9.5598, 9.5036, 9.5317, 9.363, 9.4755, 9.2224, 9.1099, 9.2505, 
9.1381, 9.2787, 9.2224, 9.1381, 9.2224, 9.1099, 9.1381, 9.1662, 
9.4192, 9.3911, 9.3911, 9.4474, 9.4474, 9.7004, 9.5317, 9.2787, 
9.3326, 9.3892, 9.3326, 9.2761, 9.2195, 9.2761, 9.4458, 9.3609, 
9.4458, 9.163, 9.2761, 9.1912, 9.3044, 9.1912, 9.1912, 9.0215, 
8.9084, 8.965, 8.9367, 8.9367, 8.9933, 9.0781, 9.2478, 9.163, 
9.2761, 9.2478, 9.3609, 9.3892, 9.3609, 9.5023, 9.3892, 9.672, 
9.672, 9.5872, 9.5306, 9.7003, 9.7568, 9.6437, 9.672, 9.9265, 
9.8417, 9.87, 9.8134, 9.7568, 9.672, 9.7568, 9.7003, 9.7286, 
9.7851, 9.7851, 9.672, 9.7851, 9.7851, 9.8417, 9.8134, 9.8983, 
9.8417, 9.8417, 9.8134, 9.87, 9.87, 9.672, 9.5306, 9.4175, 9.5872, 
9.896, 10.0666, 9.896, 9.8676, 9.7538, 10.2657, 10.095, 10.095, 
9.9244, 9.9529, 10.0382, 10.1519, 10.0382, 10.0666, 10.0097, 
10.1235, 10.2941, 10.351, 10.4363, 10.2941, 10.4079, 10.5785, 
10.55, 10.4647, 10.4363, 10.5216, 10.7775, 10.806, 10.806, 10.6922, 
10.8344, 10.6922, 10.5785, 10.55, 10.4363, 10.2941, 10.2657, 
10.2657, 10.351, 10.4363, 10.5216, 10.5785, 10.6922, 10.6922, 
10.6353, 10.7207, 10.8628, 10.9197, 10.8913, 10.806, 11.005, 
10.8344, 10.8628, 10.9197, 11.005, 11.0619, 11.2041, 11.2041, 
11.2325, 11.2325, 11.2894, 11.46, 11.46, 11.5453, 11.2325, 11.1734, 
11.5163, 11.8306, 11.7163, 11.6877, 11.9164, 12.0878, 11.8878, 
11.6306, 11.602, 11.6592, 11.4306, 11.3448, 11.5734, 11.4306, 
11.5734, 11.4306, 11.4877, 11.6877, 12.0592, 12.0878, 12.2021, 
12.1735, 12.0021, 12.0021, 12.2307, 12.2307, 12.1735, 12.2878, 
12.3164, 12.5165, 12.7451, 13.0308, 12.8594, 12.7451, 12.7451, 
12.7451, 12.6308, 12.4307, 12.1735, 12.0878, 12.0592, 12.3164, 
12.1735, 11.9449, 11.6877, 11.7449, 11.5449, 11.602, 11.5734, 
11.9735, 12.0592, 12.0021, 12.0592, 12.0592, 12.0878, 12.0878, 
11.9449, 11.602, 11.602, 11.5163, 11.7449, 11.6306, 11.8878, 
11.7163, 11.8306, 12.0592, 12.0284, 12.258, 12.2293, 12.7173, 
12.6599, 12.6599, 12.6599, 12.947, 12.4877, 12.5164, 12.3154, 
12.2867, 12.2006, 12.459, 12.4877, 12.459, 12.5738, 12.4303, 
12.5451, 12.8035, 12.8322, 12.8609, 13.0905, 13.435, 13.3776, 
13.3776, 13.6934, 13.5212, 13.3202, 13.2054, 13.3489, 13.435, 
13.2915, 13.2054, 12.9183, 13.0905, 12.8322, 13.4924, 13.2054, 
13.5499, 13.8082, 13.5786, 13.5786, 13.435, 13.2915, 13.7508, 
13.6647, 13.4924, 13.3489, 13.2628, 13.6647, 13.5499, 13.6073, 
13.3202, 13.3202, 12.8896, 12.7748, 12.8322, 12.8322, 13.1193, 
12.9183, 12.9757, 12.7173, 13.0044, 12.4062, 12.7524, 13.0409, 
13.4448, 13.5025, 13.3871, 13.5602, 13.9353, 13.8199, 13.6756, 
13.5891, 13.6468, 13.993, 14.0796, 14.0796, 14.3392, 14.6277, 
14.5989, 14.4546, 14.4258, 14.4835, 14.7143, 14.8297, 14.9739, 
15.4933, 15.2913, 15.2625, 15.0028, 14.6277, 14.6277, 14.772, 
14.772, 14.772, 14.57, 14.5412, 14.5412, 14.4546, 14.5989, 14.5123, 
14.4546, 14.772, 15.0028, 14.9162, 15.1471, 15.3202, 15.3779, 
15.2336, 15.0894, 14.9451, 15.3779, 15.4067, 14.9739, 15.7097, 
15.4789, 15.2048, 15.6375, 15.4067, 15.2192, 15.349, 15.7962, 
15.7962, 15.4789, 15.6231, 15.3346, 15.1759, 14.8776, 14.8921, 
15.0369, 14.9935, 14.5879, 14.385, 14.3416, 14.6313, 14.8631, 
14.7327, 14.7762, 14.6313, 14.8631, 15.0369, 15.1673, 14.8052, 
14.6603, 14.7037, 14.6458, 14.8341, 14.8196, 14.8486, 14.8196, 
14.5589, 14.7472, 14.0808, 14.472, 14.2981, 14.3706, 14.1533, 
14.0663, 13.8201, 13.8635, 13.9649, 13.878, 13.8925, 13.8925, 
14.414, 14.5299, 14.5009, 14.3416, 14.0953, 14.0808, 13.849, 
13.7911, 14.3706, 14.3271, 14.7037, 14.6023, 14.7762, 14.9355, 
15.0224, 14.921, 14.6313, 14.5589, 14.7327, 14.9355, 14.8196, 
14.8486, 14.95, 14.9066, 15.0659, 15.2832, 15.1818, 15.0514, 
14.9257, 14.9257, 15.0857, 14.7948, 14.8238, 14.8675, 14.7657, 
14.8238, 14.7802, 14.3729, 14.3147, 13.5582, 14.2565, 14.1401, 
14.0092, 14.271, 14.4893, 14.6638, 14.8384, 14.562, 14.5329, 
14.5911, 14.562, 14.6056, 14.7948, 14.9984, 15.0857, 14.9548, 
15.1439, 15.2312, 15.3476, 15.1439, 15.3476, 15.333, 15.333, 
15.1293, 15.6531, 15.6821, 15.8713, 15.7258, 15.8276, 15.6821, 
15.9585, 15.7694, 15.5512, 15.5076, 15.784, 15.9731, 15.6821, 
15.1875, 15.0421, 15.3767, 15.1002, 15.013, 15.013, 15.1875, 
15.333, 15.5803, 15.2603, 15.2603, 15.6967, 15.784, 15.5221, 
15.624, 15.8422, 15.6531, 16.1913, 16.3123, 16.3415, 16.2247, 
16.3708, 16.3708, 16.6774, 16.5168, 16.4438, 16.3269, 16.1663, 
16.5168, 16.5752, 16.7943, 16.546, 16.6336, 16.473, 16.4438, 
16.5022, 16.7651, 16.7505, 17.1886, 17.1009, 17.2616, 17.3054, 
17.3054, 17.5537, 17.4952, 17.2616, 17.3492, 17.5098, 17.4806, 
17.466, 17.4076, 17.4806, 17.5683, 17.5391, 17.3346, 17.466, 
17.7289, 17.6559, 17.9626, 18.1086, 18.24, 18.1962, 18.2108, 
18.2254, 18.0502, 18.0064, 18.1962, 18.0356, 17.9334, 17.4222, 
17.6121, 17.6267, 17.32, 17.5975, 17.7581, 18.0794, 18.2692, 
18.0356, 17.9918, 17.7289, 17.8457, 17.8457, 17.5653, 17.6387, 
17.3601, 16.8909, 17.536, 17.1401, 17.0522, 16.9495, 16.9202, 
16.8469, 16.7443, 16.4657, 16.5683, 17.1548, 17.0961, 16.9935, 
16.8469, 16.5536, 16.7296, 17.0082, 16.9789, 17.1988, 17.2134, 
17.0375, 17.492, 17.712, 17.6093, 17.9319, 17.6826, 17.6826, 
17.6826, 17.536, 17.4774, 17.5653, 17.4041, 17.1841, 17.1841, 
17.0082, 17.1255, 17.6533, 17.448, 17.448, 17.5947, 17.536, 18.0052, 
18.0932, 18.2985, 18.7383, 19.1782, 18.8263, 18.8849, 19.1195, 
19.5301, 19.5301, 19.8233, 19.8526, 19.1782, 19.4421, 19.706, 
19.706, 20.0579, 19.9406, 20.0872, 20.1459, 20.5858, 20.9201, 
21.1849, 20.7141, 20.9789, 21.126, 21.0083, 20.4199, 20.9789, 
20.4787, 20.5964, 20.5964, 20.0374, 20.155, 20.2727, 19.5666, 
19.9491, 19.1252, 19.1841, 19.0664, 19.037, 19.037, 19.2723, 
19.4783, 19.5372, 19.2429, 19.8902, 20.1256, 20.2139, 20.2433, 
20.4199, 20.361, 20.3316, 20.6847, 19.9491, 19.5077, 18.1248, 
18.5956, 18.3308, 18.9193, 18.6545), `3` = c(7.8478, 8.1167, 
7.6421, 7.4048, 5.3479, 5.3004, 4.8099, 4.8732, 4.9681, 5.0473, 
4.6438, 4.6042, 4.5315, 4.5156, 4.7057, 4.9117, 5.0068, 5.1494, 
4.9593, 5.0068, 4.88, 4.7533, 4.3096, 4.3413, 4.5631, 4.6107, 
4.6265, 4.5156, 4.9117, 4.9117, 4.8008, 4.7216, 4.6978, 4.5394, 
4.4681, 4.4681, 4.6899, 4.7691, 4.6741, 4.6582, 4.4839, 4.3413, 
4.2779, 4.2463, 4.1353, 4.1037, 4.1512, 4.0244, 4.1195, 4.072, 
4.1829, 4.0878, 4.4205, 4.3096, 4.3572, 4.3255, 4.4047, 4.3255, 
4.3413, 3.9769, 3.969, 4.1037, 4.0561, 4.0403, 4.0878, 4.167, 
4.2051, 4.2527, 4.1257, 4.1257, 4.2685, 4.3003, 4.1733, 4.1575, 
4.4272, 4.4272, 4.4907, 4.3955, 4.5383, 4.4431, 4.8001, 4.8398, 
5.0778, 5.4586, 5.3634, 5.3, 5.4586, 5.411, 5.2524, 5.2841, 5.1413, 
5.173, 5.0937, 4.9985, 5.1095, 5.2682, 5.3952, 5.411, 5.6967, 
5.4586, 5.4745, 5.3317, 5.3158, 5.3158, 5.1095, 5.1095, 4.8081, 
4.7287, 4.7763, 4.7128, 4.5859, 4.5542, 4.6652, 4.451, 4.4907, 
4.6335, 4.6335, 4.57, 4.7287, 4.4431, 4.3479, 4.3637, 4.57, 4.5859, 
4.57, 4.4114, 4.3003, 4.4193, 4.4828, 4.5542, 4.5859, 4.578, 
4.4812, 4.4812, 4.4653, 4.4335, 4.4335, 4.3064, 4.1316, 4.1316, 
3.8217, 3.8297, 4.0045, 4.4812, 4.1634, 4.1475, 4.068, 3.8614, 
4.0998, 4.0362, 3.8773, 3.8614, 3.8614, 3.925, 3.925, 3.9091, 
4.211, 4.2269, 4.1634, 4.1634, 4.1475, 4.068, 4.1316, 4.1951, 
4.1316, 4.0998, 4.3382, 4.7354, 4.5447, 4.5447, 4.4653, 4.5606, 
4.7672, 4.5765, 4.4335, 4.4335, 4.4812, 4.3699, 4.2428, 4.2905, 
4.3143, 4.1951, 4.2269, 4.1792, 4.0998, 4.1792, 4.2905, 4.2428, 
4.5845, 4.8308, 4.7831, 4.6877, 4.4494, 4.9102, 4.8149, 4.7418, 
4.7736, 4.694, 4.5508, 4.4235, 4.3042, 4.519, 4.6145, 4.5667, 
4.694, 4.7895, 4.71, 4.71, 4.694, 4.6463, 4.5508, 4.3917, 4.4235, 
4.4235, 4.3122, 4.2962, 4.1689, 4.3281, 4.4076, 4.3599, 4.2962, 
4.2326, 4.3917, 4.4554, 4.4713, 4.694, 4.9645, 5.0998, 5.2191, 
5.4101, 5.2828, 5.2828, 5.1396, 5.0759, 5.0282, 5.0282, 5.0282, 
5.0282, 5.0282, 5.0282, 5.5215, 5.3623, 5.3942, 5.3464, 5.1555, 
5.235, 5.1396, 5.0918, 4.9964, 4.9964, 4.9645, 5.0918, 5.2032, 
5.3146, 5.1873, 5.0123, 4.9645, 4.9645, 4.8532, 4.7259, 4.7736, 
4.7577, 4.7577, 4.9168, 4.9805, 5.1555, 5.3623, 5.3783, 5.2669, 
4.9964, 5.0123, 4.9709, 4.7479, 4.7718, 4.7638, 4.8275, 4.7319, 
4.8435, 4.6523, 4.5885, 4.5407, 4.6523, 4.6045, 4.7638, 4.8275, 
4.7957, 4.6523, 4.4292, 4.5089, 4.6523, 4.8116, 4.6602, 4.9311, 
5.0187, 4.7797, 4.7797, 5.0665, 5.0506, 5.0187, 4.7001, 4.6523, 
4.8275, 4.7319, 4.5248, 4.6523, 4.6841, 4.6682, 4.6523, 4.5089, 
4.2938, 4.5089, 4.3416, 4.238, 4.238, 4.238, 4.4292, 4.4451, 
4.9231, 5.1621, 5.2577, 5.2258, 5.2896, 5.4489, 5.2481, 5.2481, 
5.1205, 5.0886, 5.2003, 5.3598, 5.4874, 5.5353, 5.5672, 5.4874, 
5.3518, 5.2641, 5.3917, 5.3598, 5.296, 5.296, 5.1365, 5.0886, 
5.0727, 5.1365, 5.1843, 4.8334, 4.9291, 4.9131, 4.9929, 5.3279, 
5.615, 5.9341, 5.7905, 5.9181, 5.615, 5.5193, 5.5911, 5.5831, 
5.4874, 5.6549, 5.7107, 5.631, 5.5911, 5.8703, 5.9022, 5.9181, 
5.9181, 6.2371, 6.0936, 5.8064, 5.6948, 5.7666, 5.1684, 5.28, 
5.4156, 5.5034, 5.296, 5.296, 5.3279, 5.296, 5.2641, 5.28, 5.304, 
5.1365, 4.5941, 4.5782, 4.5542, 4.5303, 4.5144, 4.4984, 4.5064, 
4.4745, 4.4346, 4.6324, 4.7442, 4.7442, 4.8081, 4.9199, 4.7762, 
4.6164, 4.6324, 4.8161, 4.7921, 4.7762, 4.7362, 4.7362, 4.7362, 
4.8081, 4.7362, 4.7442, 4.9119, 4.8241, 4.7762, 4.6971, 4.7287, 
4.7762, 4.8078, 4.9659, 5.0925, 5.045, 4.9106, 5.0925, 5.0213, 
5.1715, 5.3613, 5.1241, 5.2506, 5.2111, 5.4957, 5.2506, 5.4562, 
5.4088, 5.1636, 4.8157, 5.0529, 4.9818, 4.9818, 5.1399, 5.1953, 
5.1794, 5.2822, 5.2269, 5.219, 5.1874, 5.6381, 5.7251, 5.733, 
5.7092, 5.646, 5.7883, 6.2944, 6.5949, 6.5474, 6.4447, 6.4288, 
6.3102, 6.3482, 6.3798, 6.3086, 6.3561, 6.269, 6.4115, 6.4669, 
6.4907, 6.5223, 6.3719, 6.5698, 6.5856, 6.5065, 6.3007, 6.0632, 
6.3719, 6.3323, 6.2215, 6.2057, 6.2532, 5.8574, 6.1463, 6.182, 
6.0793, 6.032, 6.1741, 6.1188, 6.0714, 6.0478, 6.032, 5.9451, 
5.953, 5.7162, 5.7793, 6.1267, 6.1583, 5.3214, 5.4319, 5.3846, 
5.424, 5.203, 5.3451, 5.274, 5.274, 5.3056, 5.4082, 5.2582, 5.3214, 
5.2582, 5.1793, 5.3688, 5.2582, 5.1319, 4.9345, 4.4529, 4.5792, 
4.3819, 4.4213, 4.374, 4.6582, 4.6977, 4.5871, 4.6819, 4.6819, 
4.7687, 4.8477, 5.083, 5.2173, 5.2173, 5.1225, 5.1936, 5.3675, 
5.2885, 5.3359, 5.2173, 5.1541, 5.0909, 4.917, 4.9644, 4.9644, 
4.9644, 5.0118, 4.9407, 4.8695, 4.8379, 4.7272, 4.7272, 4.7984, 
4.7589, 4.8695, 4.8537, 4.8458, 4.9644, 4.9881, 5.0592, 5.1383, 
5.0988, 5.1067, 5.2173, 5.494, 5.494, 5.4782, 5.5415, 5.5494, 
5.5336, 5.5454, 5.2806, 5.4071, 5.5098, 5.5889, 5.4545, 5.5177, 
5.5494, 5.5256, 5.6284, 5.5177, 5.66, 5.664, 5.6126, 5.5494, 
5.6205, 5.5177, 5.3913, 5.5573, 5.4703, 5.4545, 5.5731, 5.6205, 
6.0711, 5.7549, 5.7391, 5.7154, 5.7928, 5.9036, 5.9511, 5.8482, 
5.6662, 5.69, 5.7374, 5.7374, 5.9353, 5.9115, 6.1094, 6.1252, 
6.1648, 6.331, 6.2123, 6.418, 6.2914, 6.4259, 6.3468, 6.1806, 
6.4101, 6.3389, 6.3785, 6.3151, 6.2518, 6.236, 6.3072, 6.4101, 
5.9828, 5.8245, 5.7374, 5.7295, 5.7454, 5.69, 5.7612, 5.6583, 
5.5792, 5.4921, 5.4921, 5.2389, 5.2784, 5.3022, 5.0569, 4.9777, 
5.1914, 5.0648, 5.1518, 5.1756, 5.1281, 5.5079, 5.318, 5.1677, 
5.0648, 5.0173, 5.2864, 5.2547, 5.1835, 4.9936, 5.0806, 5.1281, 
5.3259, 5.6187, 5.3734, 5.413, 5.3734, 5.269, 5.2452, 5.2452, 
5.2056, 5.1659, 5.2769, 5.1739, 5.0946, 5.055, 4.9441, 4.9837, 
5.0471, 5.0629, 5.1343, 5.0233, 5.0075, 4.9283, 4.8015, 4.8015, 
4.7856, 4.5717, 4.3419, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 
4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 
4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 4.0963, 3.407, 3.4466, 
3.3278, 3.5021, 3.1693, 3.1455, 3.098), `5` = c(13.4319, 13.6184, 
13.805, 13.8983, 13.8983, 13.805, 13.5252, 13.2453, 12.8722, 
12.7789, 12.6857, 13.4319, 13.2453, 13.5252, 13.7117, 13.8983, 
13.805, 13.8983, 13.805, 13.8983, 13.9915, 14.1781, 14.2154, 
14.3089, 14.2154, 14.2154, 14.4024, 14.3089, 14.5895, 14.496, 
14.3089, 14.3089, 14.3089, 14.4024, 14.496, 14.496, 14.2154, 
14.2154, 14.4024, 14.4024, 14.496, 14.3089, 14.683, 14.4024, 
14.496, 14.5895, 14.4024, 14.4024, 14.4024, 13.9348, 13.7478, 
14.0284, 14.0284, 14.0284, 13.8413, 13.7478, 13.5607, 13.9348, 
13.9348, 13.9348, 14.1219, 13.8413, 13.9348, 13.8413, 13.7478, 
13.5607, 13.9348, 14.1219, 14.4024, 14.4024, 13.9348, 13.6543, 
13.4672, 13.5607, 13.8413, 14.0284, 13.9348, 14.1219, 14.3089, 
14.496, 14.2154, 14.3089, 14.3089, 14.3089, 14.1219, 14.3089, 
14.1219, 14.3463, 14.1588, 14.065, 14.2526, 13.8775, 13.7837, 
14.065, 14.1588, 14.1588, 14.065, 14.3463, 14.4401, 14.5339, 
14.4401, 14.6276, 14.6276, 14.6276, 15.1902, 15.1902, 14.8152, 
14.7214, 14.7214, 14.6276, 14.5339, 14.5339, 14.7214, 14.4401, 
14.8152, 14.8152, 14.8152, 14.6276, 14.4401, 14.4401, 14.3463, 
14.5339, 14.3463, 14.6276, 14.8152, 14.8152, 14.7214, 14.4401, 
14.3463, 14.3463, 14.3463, 14.2526, 14.1588, 14.1588, 13.9713, 
13.7837, 13.8775, 14.065, 13.9713, 13.3149, 13.0336, 12.9398, 
12.5648, 12.8461, 12.6585, 12.5648, 12.6585, 12.6585, 12.6585, 
12.8461, 12.7523, 13.1274, 13.3149, 13.3149, 13.5024, 13.5962, 
13.5962, 13.915, 13.727, 13.6329, 13.5389, 13.5389, 13.6329, 
13.821, 14.0184, 14.3146, 14.3146, 14.3146, 14.512, 14.3146, 
14.4133, 14.512, 14.0184, 14.3146, 14.0184, 14.0184, 14.0184, 
13.9197, 14.0184, 14.0184, 14.2159, 14.2159, 14.1172, 14.4133, 
14.3146, 14.4133, 14.3146, 14.512, 14.8082, 14.7095, 14.6108, 
14.7095, 14.9069, 15.0056, 15.0056, 15.2031, 15.1044, 15.4992, 
15.4992, 15.7954, 15.9929, 15.598, 15.598, 16.0916, 16.289, 17.1775, 
17.0788, 16.6839, 16.5852, 16.9801, 17.4737, 17.375, 17.1775, 
16.5852, 16.6839, 16.3877, 16.8813, 16.9801, 17.1775, 17.2762, 
17.2762, 17.8686, 17.4144, 17.3155, 17.2166, 17.2166, 17.3155, 
17.3155, 17.3155, 17.7113, 17.6123, 17.9092, 17.6123, 17.5134, 
17.4144, 17.5134, 17.1176, 17.4144, 17.4144, 17.4144, 16.9197, 
17.0187, 16.8208, 16.6229, 16.6229, 16.8208, 17.2166, 17.3155, 
17.2166, 16.9197, 16.6229, 17.4144, 17.4144, 17.7113, 17.7113, 
18.1071, 18.1071, 18.1071, 18.206, 18.0081, 17.9092, 17.4144, 
17.4144, 17.4144, 17.4144, 17.2166, 17.6123, 17.5134, 17.4144, 
17.6123, 17.6123, 18.206, 17.8102, 17.3155, 16.9197, 16.8208, 
16.6229, 16.5239, 15.8313, 15.7324, 15.2376, 15.8313, 15.7324, 
15.8313, 15.6334, 15.6334, 15.4355, 15.2772, 15.2772, 15.178, 
15.178, 15.178, 15.178, 15.0788, 15.0788, 15.0788, 15.0788, 14.8804, 
14.7812, 15.0788, 15.3764, 15.2772, 15.0788, 14.8804, 14.682, 
14.682, 14.5828, 14.4836, 14.3844, 14.8804, 14.9796, 14.8804, 
14.7812, 14.3844, 14.3844, 14.5828, 14.3844, 14.0868, 13.8884, 
13.9876, 14.2852, 14.2852, 14.4836, 14.3844, 14.3844, 14.186, 
14.0868, 13.7892, 13.9876, 13.69, 13.8884, 13.9876, 14.0868, 
14.2852, 13.8884, 13.69, 13.7892, 13.9876, 13.9876, 14.2852, 
14.2852, 14.4836, 14.4836, 14.5828, 14.5828, 14.186, 14.2852, 
14.5828, 14.3844, 14.2852, 14.5828, 14.7812, 15.0193, 14.8204, 
14.522, 14.522, 15.0193, 15.4172, 15.5166, 15.7155, 15.6161, 
15.6161, 15.815, 15.7155, 16.0139, 16.0139, 15.9145, 15.815, 
15.9145, 15.9145, 15.7155, 15.815, 15.6161, 16.4118, 16.5113, 
16.6107, 17.4065, 16.6107, 16.4118, 16.2129, 16.0139, 16.5113, 
17.4065, 17.2075, 17.5059, 17.6054, 17.7049, 18.1027, 17.7049, 
18.8487, 18.6995, 18.4508, 18.6498, 18.9979, 18.9979, 18.5006, 
18.6, 18.5006, 18.6498, 18.7492, 18.6, 18.3017, 18.6498, 18.053, 
17.6054, 17.8043, 18.3017, 18.5006, 18.4011, 18.2519, 17.8043, 
17.9038, 17.9038, 17.9038, 17.8541, 17.9535, 17.9038, 17.9436, 
18.0433, 18.1429, 18.1928, 17.8937, 17.4451, 17.8464, 17.4277, 
17.2184, 17.48, 17.7417, 17.5847, 18.3174, 18.4221, 18.2651, 
18.3697, 18.1604, 18.1081, 18.1081, 18.4744, 18.4221, 18.3174, 
18.1604, 18.5791, 18.8931, 18.9978, 18.9978, 19.6781, 19.3118, 
19.7305, 19.3641, 19.6258, 19.9398, 19.6781, 19.8875, 20.1491, 
20.2538, 19.9398, 20.0445, 20.0445, 19.9921, 19.9921, 19.9921, 
20.1491, 20.2538, 20.0968, 20.0445, 19.9921, 19.9921, 19.9398, 
19.5734, 19.7305, 19.5211, 19.5734, 19.7305, 19.9398, 19.7305, 
19.4688, 17.794, 19.2071, 18.5267, 18.4221, 18.6314, 19.0501, 
18.9454, 19.1966, 18.9344, 18.7246, 18.5672, 18.0952, 18.0952, 
18.0952, 18.0427, 18.3574, 18.2001, 18.4623, 18.3574, 18.3574, 
18.0952, 17.7805, 17.6231, 17.6231, 17.9378, 18.0427, 17.7805, 
17.5707, 17.6231, 17.9378, 17.8329, 17.4658, 17.256, 17.4133, 
17.3084, 18.0427, 18.1476, 18.2525, 18.2001, 18.0952, 18.0427, 
17.4658, 17.4133, 17.4133, 17.6231, 17.7805, 17.9378, 18.2001, 
18.2001, 18.2001, 18.2525, 17.8329, 18.9344, 18.7246, 18.4099, 
18.7246, 18.6197, 18.5148, 18.4623, 18.4099, 18.4099, 18.4623, 
18.4099, 18.5148, 18.5148, 18.5148, 18.2001, 17.9903, 18.2001, 
17.6756, 18.0952, 18.305, 18.4518, 18.3993, 18.557, 18.925, 18.8724, 
18.9775, 19.0827, 18.8724, 18.8724, 18.7673, 18.9775, 18.925, 
18.925, 18.6096, 18.7147, 18.8724, 18.8724, 18.8724, 19.0301, 
19.1878, 19.4507, 19.0827, 19.4507, 19.3981, 19.6084, 19.6609, 
19.8187, 19.7661, 19.0301, 18.5044, 18.6096, 18.6621, 18.4518, 
18.5044, 18.7147, 18.3993, 18.189, 18.189, 18.189, 18.4518, 18.6096, 
18.9775, 18.8198, 18.3467, 18.189, 18.0839, 18.2416, 18.2416, 
18.0839, 18.2416, 18.5044, 18.557, 18.6096, 18.2941, 18.5044, 
18.1364, 18.1364, 18.189, 17.9787, 18.189, 18.1364, 18.0839, 
17.9262, 17.8736, 17.7684, 17.7579, 17.6525, 17.6525, 17.4945, 
17.4418, 17.1783, 17.0202, 16.8621, 16.704, 16.704, 16.8621, 
16.8094, 16.4406, 16.4406, 16.2825, 15.8609, 16.3352, 15.9136, 
16.4406, 16.3352, 16.1771, 15.7029, 17.7052, 16.8621, 16.8094, 
16.8094, 17.0729, 16.9148, 16.3879, 16.546, 17.4418, 17.231, 
17.231, 16.8094, 16.9675, 17.1783, 16.8621, 16.6514, 16.3879, 
16.3352, 16.5987, 16.3879, 16.3879, 16.6514, 16.019, 15.9136, 
15.334, 15.334, 15.0178, 15.1759, 15.0178, 14.9124, 14.8598, 
14.7017, 14.5963, 14.7017, 14.4382, 14.5436, 13.964, 14.122, 
14.4382, 14.7544, 14.4382, 14.3328, 13.9113, 14.1115, 13.9529, 
14.0058, 15.01, 15.01, 15.01, 14.7457, 14.3758, 14.2172, 14.5343, 
14.4286, 14.8171, 14.6506, 14.4841, 14.3731, 14.0401, 13.4852, 
13.8737, 13.3187, 13.9292, 13.8182, 13.4852, 13.3187)), row.names = c(NA, 
-700L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Have a look at [rollapply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.7-13/topics/rollapply) from `library(zoo)`

Comment: I am aware of the `rollapply`, but first I want to really learn how to do it without it.

Comment: Can you clarify _in your original post_ what the exact calculation would be for the first couple of lines? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (notice I switched the order of the loops)

If you are iterating over a number:

```
for (j in 1:498){
  for (u in seq(0,5605-30,30))
{
work.on.col = j
work.dt = data[u:u+30,work.on.col] #u:u+30 iterates i.e: 0:30, 30:60,...etc. It only keeps a 30-day rolling window.
 }
}
```

If you are iterating over a date (this would only work if you had your `rownames` as dates):

```
 for (j in 1:498){
  for (u in sapply(seq.Date(as.Date(min(data$Dates)), as.Date(max(data$Dates)), 
                      "day")," [[",30))
{
work.on.col = j
work.dt = data[u:u+30,work.on.col] 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below r1 is the mean of the last 365 rows.  (Note that that is what the question asked for but there are not 365 days of data in a year since it seems weekends are missing so this is not the mean of the last year.)

r2 is the mean of the last 365 rows every 30 days.  Again I doubt that that is what you wanted even though that is what was asked for.

r3 is the mean of the last 12 months.  Presumably this is what you actually need.

Each of these is a zoo object.  It is probably best to leave them as zoo objects so you can use the rest of that package easily and not convert them to data frames but if you do want to convert then just use `fortify.zoo(r1)`, etc.

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(data[-1], data[[1]])

r1 <- rollapplyr(z, 365, mean, fill = NA)

r2 <- rollapplyr(z, 365, mean, by = 30, fill = NA)

z.ym <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, sum)
z.n <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, length)
r3 <- rollsumr(z.ym, 12, fill = NA) / rollsumr(z.n, 12, fill = NA)
```

Comment: apologies for delay. I think I see your point. Indeed I have made an English error and i miss specified. Apologies. Have fixed it.